# I have two partitions on Windows 10 (C & D), but I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 on Drive C & delete Windows 10 but keep all files in Drive D

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 on my PC's drive C where my current Windows10 is installed. All my files are already backed up in drive D.

I had already started installing Ubuntu and I always stop, advance, revert, stop...(repeat the process again and again) in the windows of

#### Installation Type:

This computer currently has Windows 10....

- Erase the disk and install Ubuntu
- Encrypt.....
- Use LVM...
- Something Else...

I had read some Ubuntu Forums and searched in YouTube, but I cannot find any EXACT GUIDE as to answer my query.

I am a novice computer user. I wanted to use Ubuntu since this is a free OS but the terminology used in the Ubuntu manual is quite "scary" for me.

And with my very little knowledge in PC, I am afraid to install Ubuntu without the help of any expert since I might lose all my personal files in drive D.

Comment: "I always stop", pls what does this mean: you stopped the process, or the process stops on its own?

Comment: Hi George. Thanks for the prompt response. I stop the process since I donot know what to do

Comment: Are C: & D: drives on the same disk or separate? Is what you have on C: purely W10, or are there any data files on there also? Run command diskmgmt.msc (as administrator). How much space on C: is taken up by W10?

Comment: Hi Paul. Drive C on windows is for OS and some windows program files. All my files are already in Drive D

Comment: If you use LVM with encryption, you will delete your "D:" drive, unless another physical hard drive. LVM converts entire hard drive to LVM volumes. So you must backup D: and should have backups if data is at all valuable. Windows confuses drives and partitions. It calls d: a drive but may be a partition on same drive as c: or may be a partition on another physical drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing to do first is to backup your files on an **external** hard drive. This is the best way to be sure that nothing will happened to your files during the process.

Easy way:
If you backup all your files on an external hard drive, the easiest way would be to "replace Windows by Ubuntu"

Hard way to keep both partitions:
For your configuration, you will need to go thought the manual partition manager (on "something else" if my guess is right as of what do you see).
Then, on your primary partition (the one which will have the same size as your Windows "C" drive (linux do not recognize drives as "C" or "D")), right click and select "format". Choose "ext4" as the file system and "/" as the mount point.
Choose "/dev/sda" as your grub point.
Then validate.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76413/discussion-on-answer-by-ad5001-i-have-two-partitions-on-windows-10-c-d-but).

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely go for a dual boot system while you're learning Ubuntu. You should also back up your data files on an external drive as a safeguard anyway. What happens if your HDD dies, or its data becomes corrupted?

**Ubuntu Installation**.

You are not going to lose your personal files while installing. You need sufficient **unallocated space** on your HDD. Ubuntu will automatically install on that. In Windows, Disk Management will let you make this unallocated space and I'd reserve about 60GB, which should easily be enough. The remaining space should be kept for your D: drive which is shared with Ubuntu. This is what you need to do. At the Ubuntu installation you choose the `something else` option, then proceed as follows:

You need 4 new partitions, `/boot` (automatically made), `/` root partition, `/home` (optional) and a `swap area`(optional). **Press the `+` sign**, choose mount-point (mp) `/` and make its size 35,000 MB, `use as` (format) ext4 and save. Press + again, choose mp /home and make size 22,000 MB`use as` ext4 and save. Use remaining space as a `swap area`. The partition sizes are just suggested to start with and can always be altered later. Continue with installation. There's a little further input needed like login **name**, **password**, (language, timezone). Everything else should be done automatically. When you restart, the GRUB2 menu will appear showing your Ubuntu and Windows boot manager options amongst a few others.